# Store string values horizontally as opposed to vertical

Tags: java, string, weka

I'm working with some Instances data and when I print out the class attributes for the data, the output prints them out individual in a vertical format. So, If I were to take the number of counts that the same word appears, they would all be unique as opposed to a string given like-so:

```
String text = "Win Win Win";

//output using code below
amount of "Win": 3
{Win=3}
```

I want to be able to store the class instances into a format like that String above so that I can count their occurrences.

```
public class testDistributionClass {
    
    
          public static Instances loadData(String location) {
            try {
              return DataSource.read(location);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              System.err.println("Failed to load data from: " + location);
              e.printStackTrace();
              return null;
            }
          }
          
          
          HashMap<String, Integer> texted(String tex) {
                

                HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

                for (String word : tex.split(" ")) { // loops through each word of the string
                    // text.split(" ") returns an array, with all the parts of the string between your regexes
                    // if current word is not already in the map, add it to the map.

                    if (!counts.containsKey(word)) counts.put(word, 0);

                    counts.put(word, counts.get(word) + 1); // adds one to the count of the current word
                }
                // lambda expression
                counts.forEach((string, integer) -> System.out.printf("amount of \"%s\": %d\n", string, integer));
            
                
                return counts;
            }         

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            String test1 = "D:/Week 1/Arsenal_test.arff";

            Instances test = testDistributionClass.loadData(test1);

        test.setClassIndex(test.numAttributes()-1);

        
        Classifier testModel = (Classifier)new NaiveBayes();
        testModel.buildClassifier(test);

        testDistributionClass splitWords = new testDistributionClass();
        
        for(int i = 0; i<test.numInstances();i++) {
                String  trueClassLabel = test.instance(i).toString(test.classIndex());

                
                
                System.out.println(splitWords.texted(trueClassLabel));

                }
            }       

}
```

output:

```
amount of "Loss": 1
{Loss=1}
amount of "Loss": 1
{Loss=1}
amount of "Loss": 1
{Loss=1}
amount of "Draw": 1
{Draw=1}
amount of "Win": 1
{Win=1}
amount of "Loss": 1
{Loss=1}
amount of "Loss": 1
{Loss=1}
amount of "Draw": 1
{Draw=1}
amount of "Win": 1
{Win=1}
amount of "Win": 1
{Win=1}
amount of "Win": 1
{Win=1}
amount of "Win": 1
{Win=1}
amount of "Win": 1
{Win=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching how you're inserting into the hashmap. Also, when you insert a value, there is 1 occurance, not 0.

```
for (String word : tex.split(" ")) { // loops through each word of the string
    if (counts.containsKey(word)) counts.put(word, counts.get(word) + 1);
    else counts.put(word, 1); // starts with 1 occurance
}
```